converting docx to mediawiki with pandoc without span tag <span>
My customer has a mediawiki web site with lots of Docx files which size of each files is more than 150 pages. When we use copy/paste to VisualEditor of Mediawiki, converts are good except some feature such as footnotes witch does not convert to wiki references. although copy/paste solution is too slow for 50+ pages docx. The pandoc solution is great but i have the following problem with it:
when i use pandoc to convert docx to mediawiki text, the output is include <span> tag for every paragraph witch make mediawiki to detect this block as a translated paragraph. i would like to have pandoc output without these span tags
the command in used is :
pandoc -f docx -t mediawiki input.docx

This is a sample of what Pandoc create from my docx Right-to-Left text :
<span dir="rtl">«وَ يُؤْثِرُونَ عَلَى أَنفُسِهِمْ وَلَوْ كَانَ بِهِمْ خَصَاصَةٌ.</span> <ref><span dir="rtl">. حشر: آيه 9 .</span></ref> <span dir="rtl"></span>
This is what copy/paste convert to mediawiki:
«وَ يُؤْثِرُونَ عَلَى أَنفُسِهِمْ وَلَوْ كَانَ بِهِمْ خَصَاصَةٌ.»<sup>[1]</sup>،
----[1]. حشر: آيه 9 .
I have text different export mode of Pandoc for all wiki solutions but none of them works fine.

It's possible to get rid of those span's with a pandoc Lua filter:
function Span (span)
  if span.attributes.dir then
    return span.content   -- unwrap content
  end
  return span
end

Use the filter by writing it to a file, e.g. nodir.lua and call pandoc with
--lua-filter=nodir.lua.
